# Properly Installing an application on Linux

Tags: linux, path, installation

I develop a cross platform application and recently ran into issues about the install location of my application. The question applies to Linux only. Till now I have installed the entire application package in `/opt/<app_name>` . In there I have a `bin` directory, which contains the application executable, a `rsrc` directory containing a few XML files (in the `bin`) and a `doc` directory containing the documentation of the application.

Like this:

```
/opt/application
└── bin
    ├── app* (executable)
    ├── doc  <directory>
    └── rsrc <directory>
```

However, my attention was attracted that on Linux the application should go to a specific location (`/usr/bin` ... maybe?) documentation and data should go somewhere else, not together with the binary (doc should go `/usr/share/doc/` but the data???) ... Can you please let me know where the application various stuff is supposed to go if properly installed?

thanks,
f.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can refer to the [filesystem hierarchy standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/). Take a look at [its Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for a quick overview.

Then you can consult specific distribution guidelines. Such as [Debian policy manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html), [Red Hat Overview of File System Hierarchy](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-filesystem-fhs.html), etc.

Comment: And what about application icons? Where do they go?

Comment: AFAIK, they usually go to /usr/share/icons. Consult specific desktop environment documentation for that. Google should help here. For example: https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/icons.html.en or http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Icons